# Steam / Dota2 with Bumblebee

Tags: arch-linux, steam, bumblebee

I'm trying to run Dota2 with Bumblebee and therefore I installed everything like mentioned here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bumblebee.

If I test my bumblebee install with:

```
optirun glxspheres64
```

Or

```
glxspheres32
```

Everything works fine.

If I start steam without `optirun`, therefore on my internal Intel graphics card, everything works fine, no errors. If I try to start steam by:

```
optirun steam
```

And the try to launch `dota2`, the screen flickers for a moment and then dota2 is closed again. I piped the output into a file to provide you with the information you might need:

- http://pastebin.com/gmn9gGLk

As far as I know I have all the necessary 32-bit libraries installed, but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the package `lib32-openal` for dota2 in addition to `multilib-devel` for steam.

[wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Game-specific_troubleshooting#Dota_2)